# How to listen AVPlayer "on seek" events?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avasset, avplayeritem

I'm looking for any "seek"-related events for AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem/AVAsset

Is there any way to listen such events? (maybe some key for kvo-listeners, not sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a workaround with KVO (please tell me if it's wrong decision):

```
case "currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty":
    if (player.rate == 0) {
        state = "SEEKING"
        on_seeking()
    }
case "currentItem.status":
    if (player.currentItem?.status == .ReadyToPlay && player.rate == 0) {
        if (state != "SEEKING") {
            on_seeking()
        }

        state = "SEEKED"
        on_seeked()
    }
```

Comment: For me it's working good (tried mostly on HLS videos, don't know if it differs from other options).

Comment: I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: How do you do this with objective c.

Comment: @norlin
My SEEKING and SEEKED is called simultaneously even if I am not end with seeking

Comment: @Saty yes, it's posible in case if no separate "SEEKING" event was catched, look at the code. I have no idea how to solve it better...

Answer (score -1):

Simple solutions is just to check the **rate** of **AVPlayer** atribute when you need it.
Check the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate

```
extension AVPlayer {


/*!
 @property      rate
 @abstract      Indicates the desired rate of playback; 0.0 means "paused", 1.0 indicates a desire to play at the natural rate of the current item.
 @discussion
 Setting the value of rate to 0.0 pauses playback, causing the value of timeControlStatus to change to AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPaused.
 Setting the rate to a non-zero value causes the value of timeControlStatus to become either AVPlayerTimeControlStatusWaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate or AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying, depending on whether sufficient media data has been buffered for playback to occur and whether the player's default behavior of waiting in order to minimize stalling is permitted. See discussion of AVPlayerTimeControlStatus for more details.

 AVPlayer can reset the desired rate to 0.0 when a change in overall state requires playback to be halted, such as when an interruption occurs on iOS, as announced by AVAudioSession, or when the playback buffer becomes empty and playback stalls while automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling is NO.

 The effective rate of playback may differ from the desired rate even while timeControlStatus is AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying, if the processing algorithm in use for managing audio pitch requires quantization of playback rate. For information about quantization of rates for audio processing, see AVAudioProcessingSettings.h. You can always obtain the effective rate of playback from the currentItem's timebase; see the timebase property of AVPlayerItem.
 */
open var rate: Float
```

Comment: How it will help to detect seeking events?